# Nodejs and Jimp thumbnail generation

Tags: node.js, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, nodejs-stream

I'm using an azure function to generate thumbnails using jimp. the challenge I have is that the content type on azure container ends up being application/octet-stream instead of image/jpeg. How do solve this?

here is s the code:

```
var Jimp = require("jimp");

module.exports = (context, myBlob) => {

    // Read image with Jimp
    Jimp.read(myBlob).then((image) => {

        // Manipulate image
        image
            .resize(200, 200)

            .getBuffer( Jimp.MIME_JPEG, (error, stream) => {

                // Check for errors
                if (error) {
                    context.log(`There was an error processing the image.`);
                    context.done(error);
                }
                else {

                    context.log(`Successfully processed the image`);

                    context.bindingData.properties = {contentType: Jimp.MIME_JPEG}   

                    // Bind the stream to the output binding to create a new blob
                    context.done(null, stream);

                }

            });

    });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Blob output binding doesn't support setting the content type at the moment. See [Blob bindings can't set ContentType and other properties](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/364) to track progress.

Currently, you would have to fallback to using Storage SDK directly. See [this comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/364#issuecomment-376900799) in the same issue for an example.

If C# is an option, check [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45916070/1171619).